# Unable to start nginx 1.9.4 with a sticky module enabled

Tags: nginx

I have nginx 1.9.4 install on my cloud instance. But I'm unable to start nginx with "sudo service nginx start" when sticky module is enabled. But when this is removed I am able to start it. Has anyone got an idea about what's causing this issue?

```
upstream uesconf 
{

sticky;

    server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9443;
    server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9443;
    server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9443;
    server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9443;


}

server {

    listen   80;
    server_name xxx.xxx.xxx;
    rewrite ^/(.*) http://xxx.xxx.xxx/$1 permanent;


    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;

}

server {

   listen 443;
   server_name xxx.xxx.xxx;

   ssl on;
   ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/keys/xxx.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/keys/xxx.key;

    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    client_max_body_size 20M;


   location / {
       index index.html;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_read_timeout 5m;
       proxy_send_timeout 5m;

       proxy_pass https://uesconf;
       proxy_redirect https://uesconf https://xxx.xxx.xxx/;

   }

}
```

Comment: I reason I need a sticky session is because the load balancer is not remembering the server ip sent the request to the backend hence user cannot login without using a forced 'remember me'

Comment: Have you checked with `nginx -t` command?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Yes. It gives me the following confirmation message. nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using sticky session try to handle standard way to reuse the same server IP according to each client:

```
upstream backend {
    hash $remote_addr consistent;

    server backend1.example.com;
    server backend2.example.com;
}
```

In your case it will be as following:

```
upstream uesconf {
    hash $remote_addr consistent;
    server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9443;
    server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9443;
    server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9443;
    server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9443;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Anatoly, this fixed the issue.

Comment: I did, it will appear once I reach the reputation level 15 :)

Comment: even though this solved the initial issue, it remains to be really slow to load the pages via nginx and session times out too soon. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Provided solution always directs user to the first ip. Is there another way that we can balance the load between four nodes?

Comment: I assume this behavior is expected (the same as sticky session), directive **hash** stick the client to its backend based on client IP address **$remote_addr**. Do you need to load balance by another attribute?

Comment: I managed to enable a sticky module by manually building by source. This resolved the issue.

Comment: @Pubudu if Nginx proxies requests to the same upstream make sure you pass original IP properly *proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;*