# Load balanced web application between UI and backend database, caching options?

Tags: caching, nginx, load-balancing

I'm not a developer...Our developers created a java application that exists between our frontend UI, and backend database.  It mainly queries the database when requested from the UI, and returns the results of said queries back to the UI - to enhance performance, it was also written to cache said queries for a specific amount of time.

In anticipation of bringing in a large amount of users, it was suggested that we create a load balancing solution (open source since we're a small start up and don't have the budget for anything at the moment).  So I implemented Nginx, which works fine however the performance immediately took a massive hit.  We reasoned that this is because each node running the java application only caches the queries it was specifically assigned (via round robin/Nginx) and doesn't have access to the cache on the other instances.

For now, since we don't have the massive influx of users (and might not for a little while), I've reverted back to just running the single instance of our application.  However I'm trying to wrap my head around the best way to solve this issue, any suggestions/opinions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nginx can keep session sticky based on various parameters, for instance [client IP address](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33215583/290338) From the other side you have a better option to cache response [on Nginx side](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/reverseproxycachingexample/) or dedicated [Memcache with direct access](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_memcached_module.html)

Comment: Just to confirm, what's the problem, exactly? It that the load-balanced configuration doesn't return consistent results because caches have different values?

Comment: Yep, basically each instance of the application only caches the information for which it is/was responsible for (cache is limited to 20 minutes).  This in turn increases search times when users are rotated through different instances (due to the load balancing) that don't have the previous information cached, and causes a decrease in performance overall from the end user standpoint.